# How to read multipart/form-data?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core

How to read multipart/form-data that is a csv file in asp.net core C# sent through api and save it in local?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync()
{
var file=Request.?? //code to read multipart/form-data  
}
```

Comment: No idea about asp.net core, but back in ye olden days of asp.net we would do it like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2 Are those methods still available in Core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the file with a model or a parameter. The file interface for asp.net core is `IFormFile`.

Form input on Html side.

```
<input type="file" name="testFile" />
```

Then you can get it like this.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync([FromForm]IFormFile testFile)
{
    var path = CreatePathUsingFileName(testFile.FileName);
    await using var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(path);
    await testFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream, CancellationToken.None);

    return Ok();
}
```